# Codeigniter how to upload image extention PNG and JPG

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

need help with Framework CodeIgniter... now i made a simple upload function. but when i want to upload file "image.PNG" or "image.JPG" it will return false.. but went i upload image file "image.png" or "image.jpg" i sucess upload it.

i controllers, i set the config with this

```
$config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png|PNG|JPG';
```

and in file /application/config/mimes.php. i also added

```
'png'   =>  array('image/png',  'image/x-png'), 
'PNG'   =>  array('image/PNG',  'image/x-PNG'),  
'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
'JPG'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
```

still can't work.. please help me

Comment: try with setting `$config['file_ext_tolower']  = TRUE; `

Comment: still not work.

Comment: while using @pradeep's suggestion, remove the code for the uppercase scenario.

Comment: `$config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png|PNG|JPG';`  is enough there is no need to change in the mime types ,try with adding `jpeg` and `JPEG` also

Comment: @TusharWalzade i already tried to change the extension with lowercase but still not work.

Comment: @pradeep the problem still same

Comment: Show the full upload code

Comment: this link may help you - https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $config['upload_path']    = FCPATH.'assets/college/images/logo/';
        $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']       = 1000;
        $config['max_width']      = 500;
        $config['max_height']     = 500;
        $config['min_height']     = 300;
        $config['min_width']      = 300;
        $config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;
        $config['file_name'] = uid().'_logo_'.date('YmdHis');
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('logo'))
        {
           set_alert('danger',htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors()))));
           redirect('somewhere');
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $logo['logo'] = $data['file_name'];
            $success = $this->institute_model->update_media($id,$logo);
            if($success != FALSE)
            {
                set_alert('success','Your Logo has been successfully Updated');
                redirect('institution/add_update');
            }
            else
            {
                set_alert('danger','Your logo is not updated due to some technical reasons.Please try again');
                redirect('institution/add_update');
            }
        }
```

Use the code above, understand it functionality and use it according. Don't forgot to load the file upload library.